# Servidor Windows 7 com Mysql 4.1

Tags: mysql, windows-7

Alguém saberia me dizer quais as limitações com relação a desempenho e numero máximo de usuários ser for utilizar um servidor Windows 7 com MYSQL 4.1?

Será que suporta um sistema utilizado por cerca de 50 pessoas simultaneamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numero máximo de usuários vai depender mais do hardware do que do sistema operacional em questão, 50 conexões simultâneas o Mysql 4.1 suporta tranquilamente, para não ter problemas de lentidão veja os requisitos miminos no link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/limits-windows.html diz 2GB de RAM, e espaço em disco.

Comment: Windows 7 é sistema cliente, suporta somente 20 conexões. Agora como se trata de conexão ao seu banco, não sei se isso interfere.